# how to create a radio button that acts as a tab controller in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc, jsp

i want to have a radio buttons that acts as tab controller same as in below jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bizamajig/mju8gzwa/

i have created the same thing in jsp with with spring tag as below.i am facing null exception in getting the selected tab value in my controller.i want to know which tab selected and based on tab selection i will query different data.

how to get which tab is selected

```
  enter code here
  <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div id="tab" class="btn-group" data- toggle="buttons">
        <a href="#daily" class="btn btn-default 
                            active" data-toggle="tab">
            <form:radiobutton path="recurrence" value="d" />Daily</a>
        <a href="#features" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
            <form:radiobutton path="recurrence" value="w" />Weekly</a>
        <a href="#requests" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
            <form:radiobutton path="recurrence" value="m" />Monthly</a>
        <a href="#contact" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tab">
            <form:radiobutton path="recurrence" value="o" />Once</a>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="prices">Prices content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="features">Features Content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="requests">Requests Content</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="contact">Contact Content</div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```

someone please help to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can know which tab is activated currently. Based on that you can query data.

Just add below code in your jfiddle's javascript/Jquery part.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
      var target = $(e.target).attr("href") // activated tab
      $(target).show();
      alert(target);
    });
```

Comment: please accept and upvote the answer if it helped you.